# Why is my pg_hint_plan Leading hint not used?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, hint, yugabytedb

I defined the join order with `Leading(b a)` but PostgreSQL, or compatible database like YugabyteDB, still join from `a` to `b`:

```sql
yugabyte=# explain (costs off, timing off)
          /*+ Leading( b a ) */ 
          select * from table_a a join table_b b using(id);

                    QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop
   ->  Seq Scan on table_a a
   ->  Index Scan using table_b_pkey on table_b b
         Index Cond: (id = a.id)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two syntaxes for the Leading hint. One just lists the table in the order they should be considered by the query planner, like `Leading ( b a )`, leaving the choice of swapping the inner and outer table to the optimizer. The other defines each join pair, with extra parenthesis, as `Leading( (b a) )` where left/right item is (outer inner). With a third table it will be either `Leading( ( (b a) c ) )` or `Leading( ( c (b a) ) )`

Generally, fixing an execution plan requires the second syntax, plus a join method hint for each join, and an access method hint for each table.

Examples here: https://dev.to/yugabyte/predictable-plans-with-pghintplan-full-hinting-1do3

Comment: I think with those are done, hint is still a hint - optimizier can choose to ignore it.